# Kafka Rest Proxy v2 with docker image 7.3.1: error when producing message with schema validation

Tags: kafka-producer-api, kafka-rest

I am using docker image 7.31 to use Rest Proxy.

I will use it to produce message to a confluent server Kafka.

I am using V2 use REST PROXY to produce records, such as this below

```
curl --location 'https:/\<my*serve*rest_proxyr\>/topics/\<topic_name\>'

\--header 'Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json'

\--header 'Accept: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json, application/vnd.kafka+json, application/json'

\--header 'Authorization: Basic XXX'

\--data '{ "key_schema_id": 100416,

"value_schema_id": 120074,

"records": \[

{

"key": {

"data": {

"externalOfferId": "XXX",

"contextCode": "XXX",

"sourceAppId": "XXX"

}

},

"value": {

"data": {

"order": {

"externalOfferId": "XXX",

"contextCode": "XXX",

"priceContextCode": {

"string": "XXX"

},

"status": "UPDATED",

"externalVersionId": ""

},....

But we receiveve this error

{

"offsets": \[

{

"partition": null,

"offset": null,

"error_code": 50002,

"error": "Record DefaultRecord(offset=0, timestamp=1686753735480, key=121 bytes, value=1956 bytes) is rejected by the record interceptor io.confluent.cloud.kafka.schemaregistry.validator.CloudRecordSchemaValidator"

}

\],

"key_schema_id": null,

"value_schema_id": null

}
```

Any clue where does it come from?

I tried to use 7.4.0 version but I get the same error.

I saw that in v3 we will have a batch function but it has not been yet released,

Comment: Do you have a requirement to use the Confluent rest proxy? If not, some other HTTP proxies for Kafka are better at producing content onto Kafka topics. Zilla is an open-source project that lets you define your own APIs. https://docs.aklivity.io/zilla/latest/get-started/quickstart/rest.html